# Setting different lengths for grid gaps in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm creating a layout using CSS Grids, and I want to have different space between each row.

I can create the layout fine by just using margin on each element, but this kind of obscures the simplicity of the code. Is there any grid tricks I can do achieve this, `grid-row-gap` only seems to take one value, which it uses for all rows.

What I'm trying to achieve is a layout like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/8swzgk0b/1/

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  width 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  /* grid-row-gap: 40px 60px; */
}

div {
  background: #838383;
  height: 80px;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.row-2 {
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row-3 {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.row-4 {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted the same. I have a layout where all gaps are fine except between the title row and the next row. There  the gap is too wide, margin can't help me.

Answer (score 40):

> Is there any grid trick I can do to achieve this, `grid-row-gap` only seems to take one value, which it uses for all rows.

With the `grid-row-gap`, `grid-column-gap` and `grid-gap` properties, you cannot apply different widths to different gaps. Like you noted, only one value can be used for each axis: One for row gaps and another for column gaps ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters)).

You could use margins (or padding) to show extra space, but this doesn't actually change the width of the gap. It only expands the row.

In the example below (based on your code), `grid-row-gap` is set to 20px. Grid items have the `margin-bottom` variations you set. Notice how the `grip-row-gap` size never changes. All changes occur inside the row.

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

div {
  background: #838383;
  height: 80px;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.row-2 {
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row-3 {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.row-4 {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to apply different size gaps between rows, then consider using actual rows for the job:

[image]

Now the gaps between rows have their own unique heights.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 5px 80px 10px 80px 30px 80px 20px; /* adjusted */
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  background: #838383;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  background: green;
}

.row-3 {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  background: blue;
}

.row-4 {
  grid-row-start: 7;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
  <div class="row-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice hack, I do think using margin is more aesthetically appealing though. Unfortunate that you can't specify multiply values for grid-row-gap :/

Answer (score 0):

you can't set different values for the column or row gaps, however, you can use css custom properties such as margin or display or you can create extra rows and columns and assign different values to them using them as gaps.

Comment: This answer doesn't add extra information when compared to the other answer

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten into this problem recently looking to pair columns and have the gap between each pair and within each pair differ.

Didn't want to manually define columns (which will require the `column-gap` to be removed) as it needs the last dangling "in between pairs" gap to be dealt with.

Found a cleaner hack using negative margins but this is really only feasible when the leading column in each pair does not have `overflow: hidden` enabled (overflowing shouldn't be a problem if `max-content` or other dynamic width is used).

Here's the demo code:

```css
.group {  
  display:              grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, max-content 1fr);
  grid-column-gap:      40px;
  grid-row-gap:         20px;
}

.title {
  margin-right:     -20px;
  width:            100%;
  background-color: #61dafb;
}

.body {
  width:            100%;
  background-color: #61dafb;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="body">Body</span>
</div>
```