# Why does a grid item with margin: auto flicker when I resize the viewport in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

I am noticing some flickering on the position of element with margin auto (child of display grid).

I've isolated the problem, please see the code below.

I am aware I can center thee element with a different approach but this one should work. I searched all over and I can't find anyone with the same problem, but I tried on a different computer and it has the same behaviour.

I expect the red box to just center in the middle of parent element and not flicker on resize

```css
section {
  display: grid;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Congrats, you discovered a Chrome bug, you can report it

Comment: thanks @Temani-afif, I reported it already...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `margin: auto` doesn't horizontally center the item in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox and Edge. [Probably a bug.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Here's a clean and easy grid alternative:

Instead of using `margin: auto` on the item, use `justify-items: center` on the container. That appears to work on all browsers.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/507to2e6/1/)

Also see:

- [The difference between justify-self, justify-items and justify-content in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48535585/3597276)
- [Can auto margins work in CSS Grid like they do in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47982767/3597276)