# How to deal with margins in CSS grids?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am learning CSS `grid` and these days I am trying to apply `grid` in places where I used to use Bootstrap `grid`. Everything is going well but I can't seem to figure out how to deal with margins in CSS grids. I am aware of `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` but that only covers the simple use cases and not all my use cases. For example:

1. What if I want `40px` `margin` after every 3rd row?
2. See the picture of design attached.  How do I achieve this css `grid`? I have marked all `margins` as **m**. Do I use explicit `margin` or do I leave columns/rows blank to act as `margin`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Comment: the picture is the design I made. I was confused about writing html/css code so I asked this question.

Comment: you have grid-gap, margin, padding, etc ... you simply need to try

Comment: *"What if I want 40px margin after every 3rd row?"* - this is not possible with CSS-Grid. Rows are not elements and `grid-row-gap` applies to **every** row

Comment: Use empty rows instead of margins. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47461444/3597276

Answer (score 0):

possible answer for your first question "What if I want 40px margin after every 3rd row?"

Assuming you are working with a 12 grid layout, you can create your grid-template-columns by including the 40px margin spacing you want as part of the layout. if you want you can also give some gap as gutter between all grids.

```css
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 40px 1fr 1fr 1fr 40px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you wanna something like this:

.row:nth-child(3n+3) { margin-bottom:40px; }

This will add margin after every 3rd row.

Answer (score -3):

Create a class (for example .margin-40:{margin:40px 0})  and put this class beside row class wherever you want to put 40px margin.